# Show navbar `<li>` according to the role of user in php

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

Here I have a `navbar.php` file where I'm calling it to different dashboard according to user role and I'm differentiating by using a `flag` in my db table. i.e., `flag = 0` and `flag = 1`.

Below is my navbar.php code

```
<?php
include('db.php');
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM login";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->fetch();


?>
<div class="sidebar" data-color="purple" data-image="assets/img/sidebar-5.jpg">


<div class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="#" class="simple-text">
            Test
        </a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav">

            <li class="active">
                <a href="dashboard.php">
                    <i class="pe-7s-graph"></i>
                    <p>Dashboard</p>
                </a>
            </li>

            <?php if($res["flag"] == "1"){
                 ?>
            <li>
                <a href="user.html">
                    <i class="pe-7s-user"></i>
                    <p>User</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="table.html">
                    <i class="pe-7s-note2"></i>
                    <p>List</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php } else {
            ?>
            <li class="disable">
                <a href="">
                    <i class="pe-7s-user"></i>
                    <p>User</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="disable">
                <a href="">
                    <i class="pe-7s-note2"></i>
                    <p>List</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php }?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As shown above. if the `flag` is 0(zero) also in db the first `<li>` is displaying. It is not going to `else` part `<li>`.

Table is as shown below.

### id | name | flag

1  |a     | 1

2  |b     | 0

Can anyone tell me what wrong am I doing here?

Comment: What does your login table look like? It looks like it could be fetching multiple records instead of only one

Comment: The problem seems to be that you are not looping through the results. You should check by printing the result. Select *From Login can return multiple records.

Comment: print out the variable. It might be a integer and not a string.

Comment: should i fetch only one record or all from login table?

Comment: @Donny Brigen `flag` value is given 1 & 0

Comment: updated the login table. kindly help.

Comment: I got it. i forget to call the session variable.